# Porting function from java (Android) to AngularJs

Tags: javascript, java, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to write an old native Android app with Ionic and I need help for the http request. I'm newbie in AngularJS (js too).

My Android code has a function like:

```
String address = "http://www.example.com";
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param", sParam));
try {
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responsegetEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String sLine = "";
    while ((sLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(sLine).append("\n");
    }
    String sContent = sBuilder.toString();
    (...parsing sContent...)
} catch (Exception e) {
    //something
}
```

and if there are more then one page I call a function like

```
String address = "http://www.example.com/result.do?page="+ iPage;
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param", sParam));
Cookie ck = client.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0);
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param_ck", ck.getValue()));
try {
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    (..parsing..)
}
```

So, I read the html content of a webpage (I'm not the owner) and I do somethings with that.

I tried $http.post but I'm not sure if it's the same

```
.factory('Service', function($q,$http) {
  return {
    getResult: function(param) {
      var q = $q.defer();
      var address = "http://www.example.com";
      var sParam = "param";
      $http({
        url: address,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          'param' : sParam
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        (...)
        q.resolve(position);
      },
      function(error) {
        (...)
        q.reject(error);
      });
      return q.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

PS: I get the

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

with that.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why you don't get a similar error with your Android code, or even if you were supposed to, as I am not familiar with native Android itself. But the reason that you get this with Angular in Ionic is that the server requires to implement CORS to get rid of that.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource itself serves. For example, an HTML page served from http://domain-a.com makes an  src request for http://domain-b.com/image.jpg. Many pages on the web today load resources like CSS stylesheets, images and scripts from separate domains.

Comment: I wrote this function 3 year ago, I don't remember very well, but initially I received No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with Android code too,  then i fixed with DefaultHttpClient (maybe).